# Codeigniter's controller data always shows on top of the html

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to get the data of another function inside the controller, but there is a problem when I load it with the view. Anyway I placed the output of the controller inside the view and it still goes to the top of the HTML

this is the controller code

```html
public function index()
    {
        $data['record'] = $this->samples();
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }//end index()

    public function samples(){
        echo "string";
    }
```

this is the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $record;?>
<h1>This is a sample</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I go to the browser it looks ok, but when you go to the source code you can see the data is on top of HTML. Why is that?

[source code from view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACBUw.png)

Comment: because you echo it, you should use return in samples()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return it

```
public function index()
{
   $data['record'] = $this->samples();
   $this->load->view('home',$data);
}

public function samples(){
    return "string";
}
```